# Casual Forest predictions gives same value for each observation in test set but different values for observations in training set

Tags: r

I was trying to understand causal_forest command in the grf package in R. When I trained the model using the following code , I was getting same prediction for all test observations whereas when I made predictions on training set predicted values were different for each observation.The importance of each variable was shown to be 0.I also checked for few casual trees with get_tree() command, and they showed a single leaf having 12 observations.Also , the predicted values gets different when n is increased or min.node.size is set to zero.

My questions is , given that every variable have 0 importance and the trees also have a single leaf(which I am presuming because I check for a lot of random indexes and I cant check for all indexes) how for every observation in the training set the predicted values are different but they are all same when predicted with test set.
Also is there any way of visualizing how the predictions are being made for training and test set.

```
library(grf)
#Train a causal forest.
n = 50; p = 10 
#n = 500
#genereate Normal random numbers with n rows and p columns 
X = matrix(rnorm(n*p), n, p)
#randomly assign treatment
W = rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)
#Simulated actual outcome 
Y = pmax(X[,1], 0) * W + X[,2] + pmin(X[,3], 0) + rnorm(n)
#run causal forest to predict Y by X and treatment W
c.forest = causal_forest(X, Y, W)
#c.forest = causal_forest(X, Y, W,min.node.size = 0)
c.forest
#plot tree at index 1
tree_1 <- grf::get_tree(c.forest,400)
plot(tree_1)
# Making test dataset
X.test = matrix(0, 101, p)
X.test[,1] = seq(-2, 2, length.out = 101)
# Predict using the forest.
c.pred = predict(c.forest,X.test)
c.pred
# Predict on out-of-bag training samples.
c.pred = predict(c.forest)
c.pred



> c.pred = predict(c.forest,X.test)
> head(c.pred,10)
    predictions
1   0.05819162
2   0.05819162
3   0.05819162
4   0.05819162
5   0.05819162
6   0.05819162
7   0.05819162
8   0.05819162
9   0.05819162
10  0.05819162

> c.pred = predict(c.forest)
> head(c.pred,10)
    predictions debiased.error
1  -0.110533258       7.859473
2  -0.048431382       7.402908
3   0.083399806       0.430714
4   0.007680637       1.557309
5  -0.010592712       3.331539
6   0.183042643       5.904475
7  -0.004142610       1.284445
8   0.092520160       1.734730
9  -0.036709332       2.479288
10 -0.019135867       1.230150
```

Comment: your test-set only contains non-zero elements in the first colum, unlike your training data which have non-zero elements in all columns. Try generating your test set in the same way as your training set. Even better: generate only one dataset, and then splitit into a training and a test set. hope it helps